# How to convert the first character of a name to uppercase in pandas dataframe python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, uppercase

Ideally, my data frame looks like this:-

| S.no | Names |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Nanda Govind Gajre |
| 2 | deepmala mohan shinde |
| 3 | jyoti dakore |
| 4 | Sonavane Ashanamdev |
| 5 | VIMAL BHIKAJI RATHOD |
| 6 | ARCHAN DATTARAO KADAM |

"Names" column is a combination of First name, Middle name, and Last name

**Here, I want the first letter of each word to be in uppercase and the rest in lowercase.**

My output

| S.no | Names |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Nanda Govind Gajre |
| 2 | Deepmala Mohan Shinde |
| 3 | Jyoti Dakore |
| 4 | Sonavane Ashanamdev |
| 5 | Vimal Bhikaji Rathod |
| 6 | Archan Dattarao Kadam |

Example

```
df = {"Names" : ["Nanda Govind Gajre", "deepmala mohan shinde",
    "jyoti dakore", "Sonavane Ashanamdev",
    "VIMAL BHIKAJI RATHOD", "ARCHAN DATTARAO KADAM",
    "KANTA VITTHALRAO TOKALWAD"]}
```

Comment: Can you add an initialized dataframe to the example? Then we can copy and experiment.

Comment: df = {"Names" : ["Nanda Govind Gajre","deepmala mohan shinde","jyoti dakore","Sonavane Ashanamdev","VIMAL BHIKAJI RATHOD","ARCHAN DATTARAO KADAM","KANTA VITTHALRAO TOKALWAD"]}

Answer (score 6):

Apply [`str.title`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) on `"Names"` column:

```
df["Names"] = df["Names"].apply(str.title)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   S.no                  Names
0     1     Nanda Govind Gajre
1     2  Deepmala Mohan Shinde
2     3           Jyoti Dakore
3     4    Sonavane Ashanamdev
4     5   Vimal Bhikaji Rathod
5     6  Archan Dattarao Kadam
```

---

Or:

```
df["Names"] = df["Names"].str.title()
```

Comment: In my dataframe, it was necessary to convert types, from 'object' to 'string' beforehand in order to make it work: ```df["Names"] = df["Names"].astype('str').apply(str.title)```